# How to post a javascript blob to MVC WebApi

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

How can I post a Javascript Blob to webapi2 controller ?

My client side code looks like this

```
//Binary image is base64 encoded string

 var binaryImg = atob(photo);
            var length = binaryImg.length;
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(length);
            var ua = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                ua[i] = binaryImg.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var blob = new Blob([ab], {
                type: "image/jpeg"
            });
```

My controller code looks like this

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/SaveImage")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public string SaveImage([FromBody] Byte[] test)
        {
//Do stuff
}
```

This doesnt work. Any ideas ?

Edit:

My post looks like this

```
 $.ajax({
                url: window.routeDictionary.incident.SaveImage,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authdata);
                }
            }).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
            //    deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                delete jqXHR.then; // treat xhr as a non-promise
                helperPlugins.removeWait();
              //  deferred.reject(new Error(jqXHR));
            });
```

Here "data" is the Blob

Comment: how are you doing post ?

Comment: Eh, you can't post binary with json... you can send a binary in three ways, with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) or just the blob and worst base64 encode it into a json or something